# Guide: Add custom font on experience(community) site using head markup in lightning builder (working 100%)

Tags: community, force.com-sites, lwr, font

Question : how to import custom font in Lightning Experience Site?

Answer:
This has worked for me. (Tested). Following are the ways

**Case 1 : when font file(.woff) is inside the zip(MyFont)**

[image]

```
/* Font file in static resource: MyFont.zip/Mukta.woff */


 @font-face {
        font-family: 'Mukta';
        src: url("{ basePath }/sfsites/c/resource/MyFont/Mukta.woff");
    }
```

**Case 2 : when font file is directly uploaded as static resource file (No zip)**

[image]

```
/* Font file as static resource : Mukta.woff */

@font-face {
        font-family: 'Mukta';
        src: url("{ basePath }/sfsites/c/resource/Mukta") format('woff'); 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). This looks like an answer rather than a question

Comment: It is great to share, but you need to arrange this as a (self-answered) Q&A. Express the problem and what you might have tried in the question, then provide an answer that describes the approach that worked.